# convert dynamically the nested JSON file data to HTML table

Tags: json, html-table

I am trying to convert the following JSON data to HTML table. This is what I attempted so far. When I ran the below script, the values in the table rows did not get filled appropriately. I tried changing the format of the JSON data but that also did not bring the desired results.

Here is my Sample JSON data(in raw_answers.json file):

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "https://url"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "assignments",
      "id": "378778ef-62f9",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "What is the day today",
        "created_at": "2017-07-09T15:14:09Z"
      },
      "links": {
        "teaching": "https://url"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is my code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("raw_answers.json", function (data) {

            var arrItems = [];      // THE ARRAY TO STORE JSON ITEMS.
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                arrItems.push(value);       // PUSH THE VALUES INSIDE THE ARRAY.
            });

            // EXTRACT VALUE FOR TABLE HEADER.
            var col = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {
                for (var key in arrItems[i]) {
                    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                        col.push(key);
                    }
                }
            }

            // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
            var table = document.createElement("table");

            // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

            var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

            for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
                th.innerHTML = col[i];
                tr.appendChild(th);
            }

            // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
            for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {

                tr = table.insertRow(-1);

                for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                    var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                    tabCell.innerHTML = arrItems[i][col[j]];
                }
            }

            // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
            var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
            divContainer.innerHTML = "";
            divContainer.appendChild(table);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please give what your current html output is and what you want your html to look like?

Comment: Your current output is literally nothing but dashes? In your questions, could you show write out the html you are trying to create?

Comment: @JoeLissner Somehow I am unable to attach snapshot here. Anyways here is the link ..scroll down ...I want my table to look like given on this link.
http://www.zachhunter.com/2016/03/json-objects-to-html-table/